# Undefined reference to NetWkstaUserGetInfo in Qt but works in VS

Tags: c, windows, qt, qt4

My project is implemented in Qt 4.7, and now I want to retrieve some windows log in information. So I am dabbling around and found this code from MSDN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370670(v=vs.85).aspx ).

Copying and pasting this code in Visual Studio works perfectly however using it in Qt gives the error "Undefined reference to 'NetWkstaUserGetInfo@12'" !

What surprises me, Qt does autocomplete and recognize NetWkstaUserGetInfo, and it also tells about the input parameters, but then when compiled it gives the undefined error !

Kindly asking, may you please advise me in this regard,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link with netapi32.lib.

See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370670%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example and pay attention to

> pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")

in the code.

Comment: Many thanks OrcunC. I added netapi and it worked perfectly :)